# Accumulate chunks of data and consume fixed size buffers

Tags: node.js

From a stream, I receive buffers of varying length.
I want to consume chunks of fixed length from this stream.
I build a buffer accumulator to accumulate the chunks in an internal array, then I can extract a buffer of a specific size by concatenating and truncating the chunks.

Here is an example usecase:

```
const assert = require("node:assert");

const acc = new BufferAccumulator();

acc.push(Buffer.from([0x01]));
acc.push(Buffer.from([0x02, 0x03]));
acc.push(Buffer.from([0x04, 0x05, 0x06]));

assert.equal(acc.getAvailableLength(), 6);

let out = acc.extract(4);
assert.equal(out.length, 4);
console.log(out);

acc.push(Buffer.from([0x07, 0x08, 0x09]));

assert.equal(acc.getAvailableLength(), 5);

out = acc.extract(3);
assert.equal(out.length, 3);
console.log(out);

assert.equal(acc.getAvailableLength(), 2);
```

Here is the accumulator:

```
class BufferAccumulator {
    constructor() {
        this._chunks = [];
        this._totalLength = 0;
    }

    getAvailableLength() {
        return this._totalLength;
    }

    push(chunk) {
        this._chunks.push(chunk);
        this._totalLength += chunk.length;
    }

    extract(n) {
        if (n > this._totalLength) {
            throw new Error("Cannot extract more than total length");
        }

        let outBuffer = Buffer.alloc(n);
        let outOffset = 0;

        while (outOffset < n) {
            if (this._chunks.length <= 0) {
                throw new Error("Out of chunks, this should never happen");
            }

            const chunk = this._chunks[0];

            const remaining = n - outOffset;

            const toCopy = Math.min(remaining, chunk.length);

            chunk.copy(outBuffer, outOffset, 0, toCopy);

            outOffset += toCopy;

            if (toCopy >= chunk.length) {
                this._chunks.shift();
            } else {
                this._chunks[0] = chunk.subarray(toCopy);
            }

            this._totalLength -= toCopy;
        }

        return outBuffer;
    }
}
```

Do you think my implementation is correct?
I am especially wondering about assigning the result of subarray to the element: when losing the reference to the original buffer, does the result of subarray stay valid?